# Python MySQLdb for CSV import into MySQL table with more columns than CSV / list idx out of range?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file which contains 38 columns. I am trying to use MySQLdb library of Python to insert it into a MySQL table (already existing, with no records) that has 39 columns (1st is a unique num id not in CSV). 
My script below is giving me a an error...

```
row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[
10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row
[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], ro
w[28], row[29], row[30], row[31], row[32], row[33], row[34], row[35], row[36], r
ow[37], row[38],)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is worth noting that several of the columns in the CSV have a 1st record(row) which is blank, and I am not importing the header(field names) row as the actual records begin on row 7. Any idea why I'm getting the error and no data.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='****',
db='artefacts')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('$MT_pipe_.csv'), dialect = 'pipes')

for idx, row in enumerate(csv_data):
    if idx > 5: 
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `nettop_master` VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,    
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)',
        row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11],   
        row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21],   
        row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31],  
        row[32], row[33], row[34], row[35], row[36], row[37], row[38],)
#close the connection to the database.
    else:
        continue

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed my code but now I am still getting an error for the 1st "date" column to appear in the MySQL table which has to accept a blank first row. I think, for dates at least, the fact that the 1st row of the field is blank, is throwing an error like this...

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect date value: '          ' f
 or column 'shortfilename_mdate' at row 1")
```

Here is my newest code...

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='****',
db='artefacts')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
dir = "C:\\Users\**\\\Documents\\webapp_1010\\cyber\\"
csv_data = csv.reader(file('$MT_pipe_.csv'), dialect = 'pipes')

for idx, row in enumerate(csv_data):
    if idx <= 6: 
        pass
    else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `artefacts`.`nettop_master`\
(`evidence_id`, `entry`, `sequence_nbr`, `parent`, `parent_sequence_nbr`, `SI_mdate`, 
`SI_mtime`, `SI_adate`, `SI_atime`, `SI_cdate`, `SI_ctime`, `SI_bdate`, `SI_btime`, `FN_mdate`,  
`FN_mtime`, `FN_adate`, `FN_atime`, `FN_cdate`, `FN_ctime`, `FN_bdate`, `FN_btime`, `typeof`, 
`extension`, `size`, `name`, `path`, `symbolic_link`, `object_id`, `ads_metadata`,`time_warning`, 
`shortfilename_mdate`, `shortfilename_mtime`, `shortfilename_adate`, `shortfilename_atime`,   
`shortfilename_cdate`, `shortfilename_ctime`, `shortfilename_bdate`, `shortfilename_btime`,   
`extracted_filepath`)\
VALUES (1, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s,    
%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: maybe this is a silly question, but why not `*unpack` the row?  `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ...', *row[:38])`?  it's a lot easier than writing it all out by hand :-).

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in Python starts from **0**.

So, if `row` has a `len` of `38`, you can index `row[0]` to `row[37]` included.  Your attempt to index `row[38]` therefore causes the error you see.

Comment: Excellent point. But I didn't mention there was that row[0] is actually the ID row in the existing blank MySQL table. That ID column doesn't exist in the CSV though, so I'm trying to skip it in the import

Comment: You **are** reading `row` from the CSV, so, how can `row[0]` possibly be an ID field that doesn't exist in said CSV?!

Comment: I changed the end to ", row[:37])"  but I now get the error          query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting... Perhaps it's because I have date and times in there?

Comment: Now you're passing just one argument, a list.  use `, *row` (why would you want to avoid `row[37]`?!) -- and count those `?` carefully (or more sensibly build that part of the query as `', '.join('?'*len(row))`) since things must match.